# GlassFish - Migrate domain from version 3 to version 4

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, glassfish-4

I would like to move a GlassFish domain from a GlassFish v3.x server (running Java 6) to a new server running GlassFish v4.x (running Java 8). The old configuration uses JNDI, JMS, a webservice, etc...

What is the best approach to handle this ? Can I just copy the domain folder to the new server ? Or do I have to export the config and restore it on the new server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right now we are doing the same thing in my company.

We were trying a few things like exporting domains, upgrading them or just coping the domain, unfortunately none worked ...

The only solution that worked without problems was coping the "important" 
parts like resources from glassfihs 3 domain.xml to glassfish4 domain.xml.
Coping the full domain.xml content or file wont work..